# Теоритичские книги об современной архитектуре веб-приложений для чайника

Tags: веб-программирование, книги, теория

Прошу подсказать книги об современной архитектуре веб-приложений, желательно на русском и для чайников.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/208036) есть исчерпывающий ответ. А вообще тема слишком обширная, нужно точнее ее определить.